# Need regex to remove lots of tags in a XML file

Tags: xml, regex, sublimetext2

The following regex

`<recode>([^<\/sumfa]*)/gi`

and

`<recode>([^#]*)sumfa>{1}/gi`

end up grabbing too much, I only want it to grab from the first `<recode>` to its next `</sumfa>` and then allow me to remove each piece in sublime text

Here is the following XML

```
       <item>
       <imd>
       <fs_ar>T</fs_ar>
       <fs_as>T</fs_as>
       <fs_af>T</fs_af>
       <fs_aic>T</fs_aic>
       <fs_air>T</fs_air>
       <kid>601</kid>
       </imd>
       <title>whatever</title>
       <recode>200</recode>
       <reto>312</reto>
       <doto>312</doto>
       <pathrela>whatever.html</pathrela>
       <realext>.php</realext>
       <kindext>.html</kindext>
       <charset>iso-8859-1</charset>
       <mime>text/html</mime>
       <sizeex>5633</sizeex>
       <sizeco>T</sizeco>
       <impsco>1.602941</impsco>
       <impscosca>1.455153</impscosca>
       <chgscosca>1.455153</chgscosca>
       <lkstae>1</lkstae>
       <lnkta>3</lnkta>
       <sumfa>1</sumfa>
       </item>
       <item>
       <imd>
       <fs_ar>T</fs_ar>
       <fs_as>T</fs_as>
       <fs_af>T</fs_af>
       <fs_aic>T</fs_aic>
       <fs_air>T</fs_air>
       <kid>23</kid>
       </imd>
       <title>Whats UP Dog</title>
       <recode>200</recode>
       <reto>219</reto>
       <doto>219</doto>
       <pathrela>wud.html</pathrela>
       <realext>.html</realext>
       <kindext>.html</kindext>
       <charset>iso-8859-1</charset>
       <mime>text/html</mime>
       <sizeex>6252</sizeex>
       <sizeco>T</sizeco>
       <lastmo>2013-04-18 08:51:58</lastmo>
       <impsco>398.818604</impsco>
       <impscosca>9.11296</impscosca>
       <chgscosca>8.657311</chgscosca>
       <lksta>2</lksta>
       <lkstae>8</lkstae>
       <lnkta>414</lnkta>
       <sumfa>1</sumfa>
       </item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`/<recode>([^#]*?)<(sumfa)>([^<]*)<\/\2>/gmsi`](http://regex101.com/r/nV9lB3)

Shorter version: [`<recode>([^#]*?)<\/sumfa>/gmi`](http://regex101.com/r/yE5eZ4)

The main reason that this regex works is because of the `?` quantifier, which makes the match lazy.

---

Online demonstration on the `?` quantifier:

> [**'?' Quantifier @ Regex101**](http://regex101.com/r/lQ8xB5)